# How to make space between text in firestore collection?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Iam adding data manually to firestore and want to make space between each paragraph
but all text come beside each other like this image.[image]

Answer (score 0):

While the Firestore API leaves your values unmodified, the Firebase console is not a great place to enter large blocks of text into Firestore, especially when it comes to whitespace. I recommend writing a small (web) page for the task, so that you can control the whitespace yourself.